# May I connect two voltage sources together if they are aprox. the same voltage? (CP2102)

Tags: esp8266, cp2102

I am making a circuit in which I have two voltage sources of 3.3V:
- First is AMS1117-3.3V voltage regulator. According to datasheet, its output voltage is typical 3.3V, but could be as low as 3.2V and as high as 3.4V
- Second is integrated power regulator of CP2102. According to datasheet, its output can be as low as 3.0V and as high as 3.6V.

May I connect those two together to use 3.3V in the rest of the circuit?

If I may not, what should I do? Maybe I can void the the REGin of CP2102 and supply its VDD pin directly from regulator? Will that be right?

Comment: You can just connect both grounds to get same reference and leave the 3v3 line disconnected. Both circuits will operate at their own (slightly different) voltages but logic levels won't change drastically as both are 3v3 systems. You'd still be able to program your ESP modules. Alternatively use 3v3 from programmer while programming and use 1117 while normal operation if possible. Or you can use diodes for reverse current protection.

Comment: Thanks on your quick comment. Your are right, but since CP2102 can not provide enough current for ESP, I must somehow provide extra current to it.

Comment: I have been using [CP2102 module](http://g02.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1k5bqJpXXXXXOXpXXq6xXFXXXE/-font-b-CP2102-b-font-USB-2-0-to-TTL-UART-Module-6Pin-Serial-Converter.jpg) to program ESP modules without any issue. In case you are facing problems, then you can go for my first suggestion - Connecting grounds together and leaving 3v3 lines disconnected. Power the esp module using it's own power source and program it using cp2102 module.

Answer (score 4):

Don't connect both regulators in parallel. Due to mismatch of voltages, current may flow in the direction you don't want.  Even, two linear regulators such as 7805 are never paralleled. Because no two IC/Transistors/Resistors/capacitors are the same. They are never perfectly matched. NEVER. In the absence of explicit authorization from the datasheet...DON'T DO IT.

Though you can tie grounds together.
@Whiskeyjack explained it in comments.